# asp.net core download excel file and messages

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-2.0, webclient

I need to call an Action Result to generate and download an Excel file, but I'd like to show a message if something goes wrong. This is ASP.NET Core 2

The generation part it is not a problem, and also the download, but I do have problems on how to call that action and show a message when there is an error.

To download the file I usually do:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult MyFileDownload(int id)
{
    if (id == 0) MESSAGE;

    var filePath = GenerateAndSaveExcel(id);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath)) MESSAGE;

    using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        return File(new MemoryStream(webClient.DownloadData(filePath)), "application/pdf", "myfile.xlsx");
    }
}
```

The GenerateAndSaveExcel function just creates a new Excel file using ClosedXml (if someone is interested I can share what I do) and returns the path of the new file.

I call the function like this:

```
<a asp-action="MyFileDownload" asp-controller="myController">download</a>
```

But I'd like to change the way I call the function because if id=0 or something goes wrong in the generate function I'd like to send message, usually I use son for that and show it using javascript.

It could so simple, but I don't see the way of doing this.
Maybe an Ajax call could solve it, but I don't know how to manage the download.

Another thing is, I like the download this way, so the file goes directñly to the download folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note the returned `IActionResult` by your action method is just an interface that represents a result of action . When the result object is executed , the `IActionResult` will call the following method of result object and write to response .

```
Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context);
```

The `File()` in your code is no more than a helper method that returns `FileStreamResult` , which is an implementation of `IActionResult` .

So just return an instance of `IActionResult` will be ok :

```
if (id == 0) return new ContentResult(){ 
    Content="not a valid id",
    // ContentType="application/plaintext",  
};

var filePath = GenerateAndSaveExcel(id);
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath)) return new ContentResult(){ 
    Content="foo bar",
    // ContentType="application/plaintext",  
};

using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    return File(new MemoryStream(webClient.DownloadData(filePath)), "application/pdf", "myfile.xlsx");
}
```

If you would like to return a json result , simply return a

```
new JsonResult(new {
    foo="Foo",
    bar="Bar"
})
```

Or if you want to leave it processed by default 404 page ：

return new StatusCodeResult(404);